# Swift 3: How to manage grouped section uitableviewcontroller flow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using Swift 3 and XCode 8.3.

How do I manually the flow of UITableViewController with `Grouped Sections` in such a way where I am able to select the cell be displayed a specified view controller and navigate back?

The following is a VC flow I'd like to recreate.

SettingsUITableViewController

- Section 1

  - General >> LanguageTVC
- Section 2

  - Help/Feedback >> Help/FeedbackVC
  - About >> AboutVC
- Section 3

  - Logout >> LoginVC

My problem is when clicking on each cell, the program returns a 0 or 1 or 2 in each section at `indexPath.row`

I want to be able to get this to work with code only. How do I enable each cell to know which VC to go to without using Storyboard? I want to be able to differentiate each section cell and the next VC it goes to.

How do I organize cells to correspond to different View Controllers when they are selected? Should I be setting a variable on each cell? Or is there a better way to abstract and manage this flow?

The following image is a similar flow for what I am looking for.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

https://gist.github.com/rlam3/4aef9009f2b4ee28b3cb1bc1d0daa6d3

Comment: Use `indexPath.section` as well as `indexPath.row` for your logic.  Can you show the code you have already?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have also attached a gist to the bottom. Please take a look. There isn't much to it besides the fact that from the UserProfilePage button when clicked on will lead to the UserSettingTableViewController. My problem lies in how to better manage section and row of cell. Because it might get into 2-3 layers deep. But I don't want to create multiple viewcontrollers for each layer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could use something like a plist with nested arrays to make your solution data driven, otherwise you could just use nested switch statements

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for this suggestion. Would creating an struct that holds objects of the same type be another way in a chain or some sort of dictionary or enum be a easier way for switch case? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use any of those techniques. I suggested a plist since that is easy to load into memory and separates your data from your code.

Comment: @Paulw11 Would love to see a gist or implementation on github so I can accept your answer. I'm not too familiar on how to get plist in such a manner. Also, does using plist enable me to save the data as well? I'm loading data in and out of user defaults already. Would love to be able to enable persistent data using this methodology. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140193/discussion-between-user805981-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `indexpath.section` and `indexpath.row` to know which particular section and row has been selected, using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of UITableViewDelegate

For example (using the above image as reference) to load GeneralVC

```
if(indexpath.section == 1 && indexpath.row == 2) {
   //load GeneralVC here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out!... But this probably isn't an efficient way to scale if you have multiple layers in the navigation controller hierarchy.